# New-Object: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'comobject'

Tags: excel, azure, powershell

i am trying to open excel worksheet from powershell azure. but i got this error

> New-Object: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'comobject'.

i have install microsoft.powershell.utility, importexcel. and check if new-object is already installed.

the command line that throws this error is

> New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

Comment: Which version of PowerShell is this (check $PSVersionTable.PSVersion -as [string] if you're uncertain)? I should note that the `-ComObject` parameter is platform-dependent - it won't work on a non-Windows host

Comment: hi mathias, the version is 7.1.4. do you have any idea how to open excel then on powershell azure

Comment: As hinted above, you need to ensure it runs on a Windows machine with Exchange installed. What application/product/resource-type are you deploying against? A VM? A CI/CD pipeline? An Azure Runbook?

Comment: from cloudshell

Comment: Cloud Shell has been running on Linux for 3+ years, it won't work.

Comment: then i will try azure function. thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

"The `cmd` that you are trying to use in cloudshell, It won't work because cloud Shell has been running on Linux for 3+ years ."

As you are trying to create excel using Azure function can refer this [blog](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10260/create-excel-file-in-azure-functions) .